# Javascript - shortest way of writing multiple if conditions within forEach loop without writing a separate method

Tags: javascript

I have below forEach loop

```
    this.cfData.customAttributes.forEach(function (currentObj) {
        if(currentObj.inputValues !== null) {
          currentObj.inputValues = Array.prototype.map.call(currentObj.inputValues, function(item) { return item.value; }).join(", ");
        }
        if(currentObj.objectType !== null){
          currentObj.objectType = currentObj.objectType.toLowerCase().replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
        }
        if(currentObj.dataType !== null){
          currentObj.dataType = currentObj.dataType.toLowerCase().replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase());              
        }
        if(currentObj.isGridEligible !== null){
          currentObj.isGridEligible = currentObj.isGridEligible.toLowerCase().replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase());              
        }
        if(currentObj.isInvoiceEligible !== null){
          currentObj.isInvoiceEligible = currentObj.isInvoiceEligible.toLowerCase().replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase());              
        }
    });
```

I was wondering is there any shortest way of writing these if conditions within the loop? Please suggest.

Comment: If each `if` has a different condition and a different result, there's not really any way to shorten the logic. You could use other syntax to remove characters, but you still need 1 check and 1 result per conditional.

Comment: only 1st if condition has the different logic, remaining 4 if conditions are having same logic to make the first letter uppercase

Comment: That's true, you could pull that logic out into a small function of its own.

Comment: use `&&=` assignment to remove `if`, kind of shorter code

Comment: @ProGu That works if the expected value of each property is either null or a truthy value, but be careful doing it if you might have e.g. `0` or `false` as a valid values for those properties.

Comment: This is fine. Shortening code with little tricks and intricacies is ok, but what will happen is you'll spend 3 hours pondering how to make your code as concise as possible, then you'll move along, then in 6 months time you'll come back to this code and it will take you 20 minutes to figure what the hell this code is doing.... If statements are fine, and easy to read. Leave it.

Comment: I agree with @TJBlackman sometimes is better to detail the code as you have it and add some comments to improve the quality of your code, that helps if you collaborate with a team and others need to modify the same code and also to solve systems issues.

Answer (score 0):

I will be answering to a more generic code, if you allow me:

1. First, if you are using single statements, the brackets (`{}`) around the `if`s can be removed.

```js
objArr.forEach(obj => {
    if(obj.propA !== null)
        obj.propA = getPropA(obj);
    
    if(obj.propB !== null)
        obj.propB = getPropB(obj);
    
    ...
});
```

2. You can always create a way over-complicated code with mapped functions (the `getPropA`, `getPropB` and so on).

```js
const getProps = {
    propA(obj){ return ...; },
    propB: obj => ...,
    ...
};

objArr.forEach(obj => {
    // Object.entries receives an object, and returns an array
    //  in the form [ key, value ][]
    for(var [ prop, getter ] of Object.entries(getProps))
        if(obj[prop] !== null)
            obj[prop] = getter(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this code which is way simpler and shorter.

```
this.cfData.customAttributes.forEach(function (currentObj) {
const arr = ["objectType", "dataType", "isGridEligible", "isInvoiceEligible"];

if (currentObj.inputValues !== null) {
    currentObj.inputValues = Array.prototype.map.call(currentObj.inputValues, function (item) {
        return item.value;
    }).join(", ");
}

arr.forEach(item => {
    if (currentObj[item] !== null) {
        currentObj[item] = currentObj[item].toLowerCase().replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
    }
});

});
```